# A list with the same type as the class it's contained within

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a simple events system, which will have many different events. So, I've tried to create an event class which allows you to register functions, taking the correct type of event, and returning a boolean.

What I want is that the method `post` in any subclass of `Event` will take that subclass rather than `Event`, and the functions in the list `listeners` in each subclass should take the correct subclass type. Here's the code I already have, which forces the function to cast to the correct event type:

**events.h:**

```
namespace events {
    class Event {
        public:
            static const std::List<bool (*)(Event)> listeners;
            void post(Event event);
    }

    class ExampleEvent : Event {
        int eventData;
    }
}
```

**events.cpp:**

```
namespace events {
    void Event::post(Event event) {
        for(int i = 0; i < listeners.size(); i++) {
            if(listeners[i](event)) return;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there some way I can get this to work with subclassed events without having to do the following?

```
bool handleExample(Event event) {
    ExampleEvent exampleEvent = (ExampleEvent)event;
    std::cout << exampleEvent.eventData << std::endl;
    return false;
}

// Somewhere else in the code
ExampleEvent::listeners.push_back(&handleExample);
```

I apologise for any incorrect code, I don't quite have the rules of the language perfect yet.

Comment: If you have a derived class without virtual functions, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: @n.m. I'd rather say if there isn't any derived class with a virtual functions, you are doing it wrong. Single classes can use the default behavior implemented in the base class.

Answer (score 0):

The common way is to use CRTP:

```
namespace events {
    template<typename Derived>
    class Event {
        public:
            static const std::list<bool (*)(Derived)> listeners;
            void post(Derived event)
            {
                 static_cast<Derived&>(*this).post(event);
            }
    };

    class ExampleEvent : Event<ExampleEvent> {
        int eventData;
        void post(ExampleEvent event)
        {
             //implement post
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use virtual functions:

```
namespace events {
    class EventHandler {
        public:
            static const std::list<Event*> listeners;
            void post() {
                for (Event * listener : listeners) {
                   if (listener->post()) break;
                }
            }
    };

    class BaseEvent {
    public:
       virtual bool post() = 0;
       virtual ~BaseEvent() {}
    };

    class ExampleEvent : public BaseEvent { // use public inheritance
        int eventData;
    public:
        virtual bool post() override {
           if (eventData == 0) return true;
           return false;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Maybe it wasn't clear, but the idea is that each of the listener functions is called when post is called. So, if I raise an event, all the listeners in that event class are notified (unless one cancels the event by returning `true`).

Comment: @SamM why not use EventHandler with the list of events, and in EventHandler post iterate over the list and call their post which is virtual?